# Web service call different service implementation classes

Tags: .net, web-services

I have couple desktop applications that are now being converted to web services so third party web applications can use services of both. Now there are certain modules of both applications that have similar functionality and we really want to use the same interface but different implementations.

So let's say there is a getUser(string id) method in the service interface/contract, would I have to change that to something like getUser(string id, string appId)?

This is for a .NET web service but I have not leaned towards SOAP or REST (or WebAPI). I am not too concerned about coding part.

Comment: What would `appId` represent?

Comment: Do you need to run only a single service endpoint, or could the different clients access the service via different URLs?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have not started coding. I have two different service implementations. So I am thinking of something like an appId to differentiate what implementation to go for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders No single client is going to need two different implementations. Also, the input and output parameters for most of the services are going to be the same (except for the something like the appId).

Comment: So, the two implementations could use two different URLs, right?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes. At this stage I am free to change as much to make this easy. The only thing I have in mind is to say "Right, here are the interfaces that are common and re-usable to both, so please feel free to implement with your own data layer. Just make sure the contract remains the same."

Comment: There's nothing to prevent you from implementing the same interface on two separate service classes. What have you tried, and what problems did you have? And, you're using WCF, right?

Comment: Yes WCF. At this stage I am going to work on a prototype and discuss it with the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have different service endpoints defined for the services (interfaces). This means you need two different interfaces and not just implementations. For example, if you were to create a service in WCF, you'd define two different services with each having a different endpoint (URN) defined like below:

```
<services>
    <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address ="http://something"
...</service>
    <service name="MyOtherService">
        <endpoint address = "http://somethingelse"
```